# How to add a Block column in pandas such that the Trials[1,2,3] is grouped as 1,2,3,4..and so on?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have this dataset(Example), In my real dataset the Trails go from 1 to 100 per subject. I want to add a block that groups them together for every fifth trial.(Or here forever 3 trial).So total number of blocks per subject is 20.
Can anyone guide me through this?

```
SubNo Trails Height Weight Nutrition %change of weight
19      1      100    30      Yes      30/10
19      2      400    30      Yes      30/10
19      3      810    10      No       10/10
19      4      100    30      Yes      30/10
19      5      400    30      Yes      30/10
19      6      810    10      No       10/10
7       1      911    20      Yes      20/14
7       2      811.   20      Yes      20/14
7       3      811    14      No       14/14
7       4      911    20      Yes      20/14
7       5      811.   20      Yes      20/14
7       6      811    14      No       14/14
20      1      222    40      Yes      40/30
20      2      222    50      Yes      50/30
20      3      789    30      No       30/30
20      4      222    40      Yes      40/30
20      5      222    50      Yes      50/30
20      6      789    30      No       30/30
:       :       :     :       :          :
:       :       :     :       :          :          
:       :       :     :       :          :
```

I want to add a column block to it which is like this one:

```
SubNo Trails Height Weight Nutrition %change of weight Block
19      1      100    30      Yes      30/10            1
19      2      400    30      Yes      30/10            1
19      3      810    10      No       10/10            1
19      4      100    30      Yes      30/10            2
19      5      400    30      Yes      30/10            2
19      6      810    10      No       10/10            2 
7       1      911    20      Yes      20/14            1
7       2      811.   20      Yes      20/14            1
7       3      811    14      No       14/14            1
7       4      911    20      Yes      20/14            2
7       5      811.   20      Yes      20/14            2
7       6      811    14      No       14/14            2
20      1      222    40      Yes      40/30            1
20      2      222    50      Yes      50/30            1
20      3      789    30      No       30/30            1
20      4      222    40      Yes      40/30            2
20      5      222    50      Yes      50/30
20      6      789    30      No       30/30
:       :       :     :       :          :
:       :       :     :       :          :          
:       :       :     :       :          :
```

Comment: @JamieOG could you take a look at this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df["block"] = df.index // 3 % 2 != 0
df.block = df.block.map({False: 1, True: 2})
```

You can change the number `3` to whatever number you want it to be.

Comment: hey thank you.It's partially working.I don't want it to start the blocks with zero,but with 1. @TYZ

Comment: also the total number of blocks is 20 per subject.And not 2

Comment: @kkkrr000 I only see block of value 1 or 2 in your expected resdult and I'm matching what you are asking for in the question. I don't see how "the number of blocks is 20" is reflected in your expected output. Please provide explanation and an example + output that shows your expectation.

Comment: Hi,I got around that.  ```df["block"] = df.index // 5% 5 ``` then the values started with 0,1,2,3& 4. I had to replace 0 with 1,1 with 2..4 with 5 to get the block values between [1 to 5] (poor coding,but worked)
I will give an example

Comment: I have edited the question with an example of 6 trails. Each 3 trail forms a block.
In my dataset there are totally 100 trails per sub.Where 5 trails form a block.